# "view app profile page" button missing

Tags: facebook, tabs, preview

I've just duplicated and re-skinned an app I've used many times before. It's a simple Like gate with a name/email form to fill in.

I've copied the details for the app config within the developer app just as I do every other time. Last time I installed an identical app was about 3 weeks ago.

I am missing the "view app profile page" on any app I've tried to create today which means I can't add it as a custom tab to my pages to test it out, or get to it at all.

Anyone know why this may be the case please?

Thanks.

Comment: This could be useful:
http://stickybeat.se/addapp/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see from [this facebook developers blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/), facebook has started removing the "application profile page".  This change will be completed 1st of February 2012.  There are details in the blog post on how to handle these changes.

Comment: Thanks Lix - from the link given I followed the link to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/ which showed me what I was looking for :)

Comment: No problem friend! Please mark this question as answered if you have resolved the issue :)

Comment: Sorted. Sorry, being a newbie to Stackoverflow I couldn't find an "answered" button yesterday when I looked. Found it eventually now though :)

Answer (score 7):

Try the following link

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=[APP-ID]&redirect_uri=[http://www.yourdomain]
```

before use, replace:

1. `[APP-ID]` with your app id
2. `[http://www.yourdomain]` with the Facebook canvas or tab URL (on your domain; not the facebook.com one)